# pushViewController crashed on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash, pushviewcontroller

I'm doing something really simple. Trying to pushViewController. It works great on iPhone but on iPad, it crashes! SIGABRT:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x35d85324:  mov    r12, #328
0x35d85328:  svc    #128
0x35d8532c:  blo    0x35d85344                ; __pthread_kill + 32
0x35d85330:  ldr    r12, [pc, #4]             ; __pthread_kill + 24
0x35d85334:  ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
0x35d85338:  b      0x35d85340                ; __pthread_kill + 28
0x35d8533c:  stmibeqr4, {r5, r6, r7, r10, r11}
0x35d85340:  bx     r12
0x35d85344:  bx     lr
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

```
Principal *cvc;

NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"]) {
    cvc = [[Principal alloc] initWithNibName:@"Principal" bundle:nil];
} else {
    cvc = [[Principal alloc] initWithNibName:@"Principal_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

[cvc setImg:flippedImage];

if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"]) {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];

} else {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];

}

[cvc release];
```

Comment: You should use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM, not compare strings.

Comment: Im using UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM now... But, anyway, this is not what is causing the crash!

Comment: That's why I didn't put it as a solution ;) Just saying...

Answer (score 2):

I think it is much easier to check for the UI Interface Idiom:

```
    Principal *cvc;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() = UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        cvc = [[Principal alloc] initWithNibName:@"Principal" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        cvc = [[Principal alloc] initWithNibName:@"Principal_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    [cvc setImg:flippedImage];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
    [cvc release];
```

Additionally you are doing the same thing in both cases of the last `if` statement, so you can just remove it as I have done on the code.

In order to help you more, I need to see the actual exception text thrown before the crash.

I can imagine the problem is that `self.navigationController` is defined on the iPhone but not on the iPad, or that the initialiser used for iPad is returning a `nil` VC, and pushing a `nil` view controller will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you for help! How can I get the "actual exception text thrown before the crash" ? Thank you!

Comment: All I can see here is:

libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x37e0d324:  mov    r12, #328
0x37e0d328:  svc    #128
0x37e0d32c:  blo    0x37e0d344                ; __pthread_kill + 32
0x37e0d330:  ldr    r12, [pc, #4]             ; __pthread_kill + 24
0x37e0d334:  ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
0x37e0d338:  b      0x37e0d340                ; __pthread_kill + 28
0x37e0d33c:  stmibeqr4, {r5, r6, r7, r10, r11}
0x37e0d340:  bx     r12
0x37e0d344:  bx     lr
How can I get the full text?

Comment: The text is shown on the console when the exception is thrown, something like this: `2012-09-03 15:21:53.575 YourAppName[74497:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:`

Answer (score 1):

There is someting wrong with this;

```
Principal *cvc;
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"]) {
    cvc = [[Principal alloc] initWithNibName:@"Principal" bundle:nil];
} else {
    cvc = [[Principal alloc] initWithNibName:@"Principal_iPad" bundle:nil];
    // This should be allocated with the class Principal_iPad not Principal.
}
```

It should be something like this,

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] || [deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"]) {
    Principal *cvc = [[Principal alloc] initWithNibName:@"Principal" bundle:nil];
    [cvc setImg:flippedImage];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
    [cvc release]
} else {
    Principal_iPad *cvc = [[Principal_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"Principal_iPad" bundle:nil];
    [cvc setImg:flippedImage];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
    [cvc release]
}
```

Comment: Principal_iPad is pointing to the class Principal... Principal_iPad are just a different xib with an ipad layout!

Comment: oh okay..maybe there is something wrong with the pointing the class, it maybe returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

To get Actual Exception You have to set `NSZombieEnabled`. To set `NSZombieEnabled` goto Product->Edit Scheme->Arguments In Arguments you will find 'Environment Variables' here just Click on `+` sign and add `NSZombieEnabled` and check the checkbox beside that. Then you can see the exception. I thought the problem may not be with NavigationController. It may be in the PricipalViewController , Just check it by putting breakPoints at `ViewDidLoad` in PrincipalViewController.

Comment: `NSZombieEnabled`, not `NSZoombieEnabled`!

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with your xib like some connections that can not exist(which usually come along when you copy xib elements and forget to remove the selectors, etc). You can find your stack trace by adding the following code to your appDelegate:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
   NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
   NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
   // Internal error reporting
}
```

The above method should be the first one in your `appDelegate.m`

Then, add `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);` as the first line in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);//should be the first line
    ....
    ....
}
```